# Remove double slashes from several strings with sed (current idea not working)

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace the double backslashes (//) from the items below:

```
//listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
//listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
//recursion yes;
```

*(I don't know if it's important to mention, but there are several spaces in front of those results. Probably not, but I thought I would mention this anyways.)*

I only have limited knowledge with sed (and I don't want to use anything else), but for some reason I cannot get it removed. I also tried using "|" as a divider (or what's the name for it), but no luck.

Things I tried:

```
sed -i 's|^//recursion yes;*|recursion yes;*|' /etc/named.conf
```

and:

```
sed 's#^//[ \t]recursion$#recursion#g' /etc/named.conf
```

and

```
sed 's#^//[\t]recursion$#recursion#g' /etc/named.conf
```

(the last two examples are based on something I found in a different thread somewhere on this site, but also does not give a correct result back. In other words it refuses to remove the two slashes (//).

So far I only tried it with "//recursion yes;", because I wanted to make that work first, but since I am already failing on that.

And please explain what I am doing wrong. Thank you!
If you are willing, can someone also give an example with awk also. So that I can use that also in the near future as an alternative to sed. Apparently awk is more desired than sed? Or is that a personal preference in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I don't know if it's important to mention, but there are several spaces in front of those results. Probably not, but I thought I would mention this anyways.*

It is extremely important - **if** you use `^` to anchor your match pattern to the start of the string. In particular:

- `^//recursion` will only match exactly at the start
- `^//[ \t]recursion` will only match when `//` is exactly at the start and there is exactly one space or tab character after
- `^//[\t]recursion` will only match when `//` is exactly at the start and followed by exactly one tab

In addition, you seem confused about what `*` means in a regular expression (as distinct from a shell glob - or wildcard) - in regex, it's a *quantifier* meaning zero or more of the preceding expression.

Assuming the whitespace comes before the `//`, what I'd probably do is something like

```
sed -E '\:[ \t]*//recursion|listen-on: s://::' named.conf
```

Breaking it down

- `\:^[ \t]*//recursion|listen-on:` match zero or more spaces-or-tabs followed by `//` then `recursion` or `listen-on`
- `s://::` substitute `//` by nothing only on matching lines

I used `:` as a delimiter in place of the default `/` to avoid confusion with the pattern string, and removed the `-i` for testing. `-E` enables extended matching which makes `|` mean `or`.

If you need to allow for arbitrary whitespace on both sides of the `//`, you can change the match expression to

```
\:^[ \t]*//[ \t]*(recursion|listen-on):
```

You can also use `[[:blank:]]` in place of `[ \t]` if you prefer (or even `[[:space:]]` which also includes vertical whitespace - the distinction is moot in this context since you are processing one line at a time).

---

With awk, things are slightly different - at least if you use the default field separator. In that case, awk strips off leading whitespace, so you can anchor the `//` to the start of the first field:

```
awk '$1 ~ /\/\/recursion/ {sub(/\/\//,"",$1)} 1'
```

Note that only GNU awk provides an in-place editing option. In awk, you could also consider using fixed string matching like

```
'$1 == "//recursion" || $1 == "//listen-on"
```

Also note that these methods will both strip leading whitespace from the output.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer and information! Very useful! I will make good use of it and will use it as a reference for future "issues". Thank you once again!

Comment: @Joanne you're welcome - I just noticed that my answer assumes the whitespace occurs **before** the `//` whereas re-reading your question it seems it's between the `//` and the rest of the string to be matched - that makes my answer less relevant. I hope you are able to modify it appropriately.